# How do you import two different text widgets into one frame in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Sorry I am new to Python and I am very confused by this. I am writing a program that displays a drop down menu, and I wish to have it display a printed input based on which option you choose from the drop-down menu.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

def roll(n):
    return random.randint(1,n)

def calc():
    thing = var.get()
if (thing == 'Barbarian'):
    print ()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
root.title("Gold Calculator")

var = tk.StringVar(root)
var.set('-Select a class-') 

choices = ['Barbarian', 'Bard', 'Cleric', 'Druid','Fighter', 'Monk',     'Paladin', 'Ranger', 'Rougue', 'Sorcerer', 'Warlock', 'Wizard']

option = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate Gold", command=calc)
button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to know how to create a text box to the right of the drop down menu that prints some text based on the class that you choose. How would I do this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: "text widget" means something very specific in Tkinter. Are you referring to the `Text` widget, or a `Label` widget? Your title says "text widget" but it seems you might really mean a label. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `tk.Label()` widget and its `textvariable` argument to bind a `StringVar` to it. Whenever the attached `StringVar` gets updated, the label will change its content accordingly:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

def roll(n):
    return random.randint(1, n)

def calc():
    thing = var.get()
    if (thing == 'Barbarian'):
        print ()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (500, 80, 200, 150))
root.title("Gold Calculator")

selection = tk.StringVar(root)
selection.set('-Select a class-') 


choices = ['Barbarian', 'Bard', 'Cleric', 'Druid', 'Fighter', 'Monk', 'Paladin', 'Ranger', 'Rougue', 'Sorcerer', 'Warlock', 'Wizard']


option = tk.OptionMenu(root, selection, *choices)
option.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate Gold", command=calc)
button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)

label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=selection)
label.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Since we got that working we can have a look at how to get a selection-depending text in the label widget. To achieve this, we can connect a callback function which observes the StringVar connected with the OptionMenu widget. Within that callback we can read the current content as a key and get the desired content of the label widget as a value out of a dict.

Please see comments in code for further details:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

def roll(n):
    return random.randint(1, n)

def calc():
    thing = var.get()
    if (thing == 'Barbarian'):
        print ()

# define a callback function in order to set the content of the label widget dependent on the selection
# reads the current content of StringVar `selection`, gets the desired value from the dict `d` and
# writes it to the StringVar `view_text`
def observe_option_menu(*args):
    view_text.set(d.get(selection.get()))

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (550, 80, 200, 150))
root.title("Gold Calculator")

# create another StringVar and connect a callback function to it.
# hence trance as the 'w' flag, this callback will be fired whenever someone writes to the variable
selection = tk.StringVar(root)
selection.set('-Select a class-') 
selection.trace('w', observe_option_menu)

choices = ['Barbarian', 'Bard', 'Cleric', 'Druid', 'Fighter', 'Monk', 'Paladin', 'Ranger', 'Rougue', 'Sorcerer', 'Warlock', 'Wizard']

# lists `texts` contains sample data in order to get key-value-pairs to combine selection with text of label
texts =  ['VniC', '3DhO', 'CWm0', '8Cf9', 'avNN', 'SUnD', 'lp3R', 'Gtgk', 'FwvV', 'XzH1', 'CyGO', 'UASr']

# create a dict `d` out from the lists given above, you could use a dict directly instead of two seperate lists
d = dict(zip(choices, texts))

view_text = tk.StringVar(root)
view_text.set('Content depends on selection') 

option = tk.OptionMenu(root, selection, *d.keys())
option.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate Gold", command=calc)
button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)

# create a Label widget `label` and place it using pack geometry manager
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=view_text)
label.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```